# 8-bitify image in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa, image-processing

In an application I'm working on in iOS, I need to get a picture from the user, then convert it to that blocky, pixelated 8-bit style that we all love. I assume I use some Quartz/CoreImage (I've got my Mac and iOS dev mixed up methinks) filter to active this? I've never used any of these, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This process is very simple to write yourself. You can use CoreGraphics to render to a bitmap using a CGImage and a CGBitmapContext. Then manipulate the pixel values directly.

8 bit representations would either:

- use CLUTs/color maps
- or RRRGGGBB format

The former is more complicated. If this is new to you, then begin by converting the pixel values to approximate RRRGGGBB. Assuming you know how to bitshift and create a bitmap via CoreGraphics (plenty of examples exist), you're all set!

Comment: Using Core Image will actually be a lot faster than doing this, as it leverages the GPU. You also don't need to write any image manipulation code if you use Core Image, which is always good…

Comment: But you can't support iOS 4 (or 3).

Comment: @Rob 1) Good point about the GPU, but certainly not faster in all scenarios. 2) CI doesn't guarantee what will happen where, and for what reasons - CG (as an example based on a similar concept) certainly does a lot of work off the GPU. 3) Your example is an approximation of the effect - but it does look good. 4) CI is not available prior to iOS 5. Bonus) Image manipulation code is fun!!! …for some of us ;) So I decided another answer was fine when I answered.

Answer (score 4):

You could use Core Image, specifically the `CIColorPosterize` and `CIPixellate` filters. Core Image has the advantage that it takes advantage of the GPU and will be a LOT faster than manually manipulating the bitmap.

A simple example would be something like:

```
NSURL* imageURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForImageResource:@"yourSourceImage"]];
CIImage* inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

CIFilter* posterize = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorPosterize"];
[posterize setDefaults];
[posterize setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:8.0] forKey:@"inputLevels"];
[posterize setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];

CIFilter* pixellate = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIPixellate"];
[pixellate setDefaults];
[pixellate setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:4.0] forKey:@"inputScale"];
[pixellate setValue:[posterize valueForKey:@"outputImage"] forKey:@"inputImage"];

CIImage* outputImage = [pixellate valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
[inputImage release];

//do something with outputImage
```

You should play around with the "Core Image Fun House" app which you can find in `/Developer/Applications/Graphics Tools` to obtain values for the filters that give you the result you want.

You should bear in mind that Core Image is only available as of iOS 5.

Comment: I'm trying to use this code, but I just can't get it to work. I've modified it slightly to use NSClassFromString as my app must support iOS 4.3. I'm using it this way: http://pastebin.com/5hwb0xcr My image view remains blank, but if I try to convert my inputted CIImage back to an UIImage, my image view shows the original image. Any ideas?

Comment: Argh. I just tried this on iOS and both of the filters in question return `nil`. After checking the iOS docs, I discovered that neither `CIColorPosterize` nor `CIPixellate` are available on iOS, they appear to be Mac-only. I'm sorry for leading you down the garden path on this one, I had forgotten that iOS has only a subset of the Core Image filters.

Comment: Darn, I guess I'll need to roll my own image processing code. Thanks for the answer, though.